# Equivalent searching using "like" with "match()"

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%word'
```

Now what is its the equivalent of above query in fulltext indexed?

It should be noted that this does note work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

---

**EDIT**

I want to select 'test' in this sentence:

*it is a ttest.*

Comment: There is no equivalent.  I don't think MySQL allows positioning information relative to the beginning and end of the document.  The best you can do is use `match()` followed by a `like`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think MySQL directly supports this.  You can speed the query by doing:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
     ) t
WHERE col LIKE '%word';
```

(I'm not 100% sure that the subquery is needed.)

If you know that this will be a common type of search, you can hack a solution.  Modify each of the documents to be something like:

```
BEGINDOCMARKER blah blah blah ENDDOCMARKER
```

Then you can search for:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('"word ENDDOCMARKER"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If you do take this approach, be careful with the marker.  It is tempting to use `^` and `$` (ala regular expressions), but these will be unindexed due to the minimum word length and other reasons.  Some uncommon jumble of characters is a good bet.

Also note that this makes the text longer and you will probably want to remove these words for presentation purposes.  If space is not an issue, duplicate the field, one for searching and one for presenting.  This can be useful for another reason: handling synonyms.  Or, consider other text search alternatives.  Other tools do allow positioning information in the query.

Comment: Actually your first query is wrong, because `MATCH()` is unable to find what I want *(then searching in the result of `MATCH()` by `LIKE()` is useless)*. Also your second query is vain, because I can do that using a star like this: `AGAINST('word'* IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. In fact my question is about prefix (not suffix), I mean is I need to select "test" in "ttest" or select "ello" in "hello" using `MATCH()`. Is it possible?